# How to get TRUE or FALSE regarding to multiple cells in a row with the column "title" Google Spreadsheet

Tags: dictionary, lambda, boolean, logic

#### I want to get a automatically created Holiday packing list.

- On the first sheet I define the holiday conditions: is it warm or
  cold, hotel... flight etc
- On another sheet I have table with checkboxes in which I pre-define
  IF the item in column A is affected by condition i defined.
- In row 4 I have the checked value (True or False) from my first sheet.
- In row E I want to get a true IF there is any where in the same row the condition in row 4  TRUE and the checkbox clicked.

In my shown screenshot I made it work for a small test area (F16:J22) in combination with F4:J4 but I would have to make a big formula.

*I know.. but I don't know HOW... there is a better solution probably with lambda or arrayformula :(*

[image]